# How to Invoke a specific implemented class of a Interface

Tags: java, class, interface, enums

What I try to accomplish is to invoke the Interface of a specific class.
I use a Enum to fill in the .class and to get the Interface of that Class.
So how can I return the interface?
I would like to avoid reflection if possible.

Thanks in advance.

```
public interface GameInterface {
    void start();
    void sop();
}

public enum Game{
    MINESWEEPER(MineSweeper.class),
    MARIO(Mario.class);

    private Class c;

    public Game(Class c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public GameInterface getGameInterface() {
        // return Interface of the class 
        // So I can call for instance MINESWEEPER.getGameInterface().start()

        // At this momement I use return: 
        // ((GamemodeInterface)this.c.getDeclaredMethod("getInstance", new Class[0]).invoke(null, new Object[0]));
        // *MineSweeper and Mario are Singleton, thats why getInstance
    }
}
```

Clarification:
The main goal is to acces Start() and Stop() methods at MineSweeper and Mario class.
The usage should be something like: MINESWEEPER.getGameInterface().start()
But at this moment I don't know a solid solution to get the Interface with knowing of the .class.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't understand what you're asking. If you don't get a decent answer soon, please try clarifying your question a bit.

Comment: You need an **instance** of a class (i.e. something created with `new`) in order to invoke non-static methods.

Comment: you need to return anything that implements of type GameInterface

Comment: There is no static interface in Java, you cannot call a static method through an interface.

Comment: Why not just use a factory method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better idea:

1. Implement `GameInterface` to each Game of your class with implying name of your choice.
2. Declare `enum` with abstract function `createGame` and return with the instance of the Game class you are expecting with implementation of this `createGame` function to each `enum` constant:

   ```
   class MineSweeper implements GameInterface
   {
       // your code
   }

   class Mario implements GameInterface
   {
      // your code
   }

    public enum GameType
   {
     MINESWEEPER
     {
        public GameInterface createGame()
        {
         return new MineSweeper();
        }
     },

     MARIO
     {
        public GameInterface createGame()
       {
         return new Mario();
        }
     }

      public abstract GameInterface createGame();
   }
   ```

If you intended to use singleton pattern, although i could not be so sure from your question but as @GaborSch  has suggested: you could make use of `MineSweeper.getInstance()` function inside the `createGame()` of `enum` constants. However, try thinking to use an `enum` while implementing a Singleton too, as is suggested in Effective Java book with detail explanation.